# strpos(); return position of separate word

Tags: php, strpos

How to return position of separate word for example:

```
echo strpos("I love academyphp, I love php too!","php");
```

I want to find only position of free words *php* and ignore position of *academyphp*.

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: So you gave up or what?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a more versatile function. `\b` is a word boundary:

```
preg_match('/\bphp\b/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $matches[0][0] . ' found at position ' . $matches[0][1];
```

If you need to find more than one use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: that will match also $php€, who knows if it is free enough.

Comment: I would say to post your pattern but it looks like OP has abandoned this.

Answer (score -1):

Add space to "php" and add 1:

```
echo strpos("I love academyphp, I love php too!"," php")+1;
```

Or two spaces, if you want it to be "free" on both sides:

```
echo strpos("I love academyphp, I love php too!"," php ")+1;
```

Comment: because the space moves searched string one up.